# I get this error after trying to install Imagemagick on XAMPP

Tags: php, imagemagick, xampp

I get this error after trying to install imageMagick on XAMPP

```
The procedure entry point php_checkuid_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll
```

What could be going wrong ?  below are the instructions I followed , I need to install image magick then ghostscript to turn PDF files into images..

```
Head over to http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/ and grab 6.5.4.6-Q16 (excellent mirror, THANKS!)
Install on XAMPP machine to directory /XAMPP/ImageMagick/
Ensure you have add path selected during install, or manually add path)
Grab a matching DLL which you can find HERE (Linked to php_imagick.dll, TS on http://www.sk89q.com/2010/03/vc6-windows-binaries-for-imagick-2-3-0/)
Edit your PHP.INI, uncomment or add-> extension=php_imagick.dll (php.ini found in xampproot/php/
Stop apache, save work, restart machine
You should have no error upon boot, if version mismatch ensure you have not had a prior version of Imagick installed
```

Answer (score 3):

Your DLL seems to be outdated, you'll have to find another DLL more recent, like here http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/ for example.

Try to find the builded DLL for your PHP version, or it will always fail.